# How to show image for 3 seconds

Tags: p5.js

I am making a game and one of your opponents attacks is an explosion, if you are in his range he will attack, but the attack only lasts one frame. How can I make the attack last 3 seconds?
This is the code, player is a class and this code is in the class of the opponent.

```
if(player.x-90<=this.x && player.x+290>=this.x && player.y-190<=this.y && player.y+240>=this.y && frameCount % 600 == 0) {
        image(explosion,player.x,player.y,180,180);
        player.health-=this.damage;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store data on the opponent class to remember the position and start time of the explosion, then every update check the current time against the start time; if it's been less than 3 seconds, draw the image, if not remove the explosion data.
If multiple explosions can happen within 3 seconds, make that a list.